# React Router V6 with { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } routing not working, throws blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

I'm using latest version of `react@18.2.0`, `react-dom@18.0.6`, `react-router-dom@^6.4.2`.

I created this app with `BrowserRouter`, `Routes`, and `Route` for routing between the components, but it's not working, I'm getting blank page.

I am also getting error like "invalid use of hooks / useref". I Don't know where I'm doing wrong.

Email.tsx

```
import React from "react";

const EmailPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <hr/>
      <h2>Email</h2>
      <hr/>
      <h3>abc@xyz.com</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EmailPage;
```

Contact.tsx

```
import React from "react";

const ContactPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <hr/>
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <hr/>
      <h3>BBSR, Odisha, India</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ContactPage;
```

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";

const App = () =>{   
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome Home</h1>
      <nav>
        <a href="/email">Email</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

import EmailPage from './route-components/Email';
import ContactPage from './route-components/Contact';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App/>}/>
      <Route path="email" element={<EmailPage/>}/>
      <Route path="contact" element={<ContactPage/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-route-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.65",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code you've shared that would cause blank pages to render. You will want to import and use the `Link` component from RRD instead of the raw anchor tags (`<a>`) in your `nav` section. The anchor tag will reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove this code `as HTMLElement` and check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-monad-p1klrr?file=/src/index.js
It is working for me.

Comment: I used  TSX files so I used HTMLElement there. Also I tried without HtmlElment by creating another API using JS template  but it's not working. Giving Same Error.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component:

    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42827:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue Resolved:**
Everything is correct in the code.I followed the below steps and it start working completly fine.
-> command this in the project file: **`'npm audit fix --force'`**
-> then command : **`'npm cache clean --force'`**
-> then restart the IDE and do the `'npm start'`